# C# how to implement "singleton" method

Tags: c#, singleton

We all know about the singleton pattern.

How do you implement a singleton "method"? - a method that is called only once and any other call will do nothing.

I can think a few ways (including Lazy - if (!.IsValueCreated) {... value.method();}) but how would you implement it?

Comment: -1 I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: check for equality to a `certain value` in that method and only do the work if it IS that `certain value`, then set it to `another value` in that method after your work has been done and ensure that value is not reset to the `certain value` again elsewhere

Comment: lets assume the method is from external API that you can not control but must not be called a second time :)

Comment: you could always wrap that `external API method` into your own so you regain control ;)

Comment: This is not the singleton pattern.

Comment: @Grzenio true, but noone ever claimed it was

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, that is how I interpreted the first sentence of the question. I apologize if I got it wrong :)

Comment: if method is external and you are lazy to write wrapper, then check flag every time you call the method. If there are many of such methods (has to be run once), then you need (obviously) many flags. As flags has to be saved somewhere, making singleton for a wrapper is more than a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so there is something like a singleton method.

If you want your method to do execute the block of code only once then you can do that. This can be done in several ways, one of them could be as follows-

```
   public class Foo
    {
      private static bool _isInitialied;


      public void Initialize()
      {
        if(_isInitialied) 
            return;
        //TODO: Initialization stups.
        _isInitialied = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: there isn't. I just like to see what solutions are people can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using actions:

```
public class Test
{
    private Action _action;

    private void DoSomething()
    { 
        // Do something interesting
        _action = DoNothing;
    }

    private void DoNothing()
    {
    }

    public Test()
    {
        _action = DoSomething;
    }

    public void Call()
    {
        _action();
    }
} // eo class Test
```